# How do I fix "Error: Cannot find module '@keyv/sqlite'" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm

Whenever I try to run my program i get the error `Error: Cannot find module '@keyv/sqlite`.
I've tried to reinstall everything, but no matter what I do, I continue to get this error.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Can you check your `package.json` and see if the `@keyv/sqlite` is there? You might have forgotten to install it in the first place

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!